# How to fix 'replace 0 value for blank formula'

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to write formula that use data from another file, for example in field X in cell A1 value = 0. From another file i need to read value and if A1=0 lets left it with blank cell.

I tried formula to replace value 0 with blank  but when i put loaded data to SAP from excel file it's still show value 0 but should blank

```
=IF(OR('[FILE_1.xlsm]Product Data'!$G237="";'[FILE_1.xlsm]Product Data'!G237=0);"";SUBSTITUTE('[test.xlsm]Product Data'!$G237;",";"."))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it with your formula and its working exactly as you wanted.  Maybe you have some custom setting on your workbook?
https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/pro-tip-three-ways-to-hide-zero-values-in-an-excel-sheet/